# Catch a non-specific exception when the caller apply the same action for each exception handle

Tags: java, exception

I have to dynamically instantiate  certain class based on runtime configuration. So, I need to invoke the method *newInstance()* and accordingly handle the exceptions:

```
try {
    clazz.newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    logger.error(ex, ex);
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    logger.error(ex, ex);
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

In this point of my code the only way to handle this exceptions is by attempting to log the error and present a friendly message to the user (rethrowing the exception as runtime ,the view layer will 
catch the runtime exception)

```
<exception class="java.lang.Exception">
  <redirect view-id="/error.xhtml" />
</exception>
```

The point is that if I can't reasonable recover the error for any exception throw when method *newInstance()*  is called and for each exception the same action  is applied (log and rethrow the exception), is a better approach to replace the code above handling a non-specific exception like :

```
try {
    clazz.newInstance();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error(ex, ex);
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a limitation of Java. I believe Java 7 may address this.

Until then, however, you are stuck with two unpalatable options:

1. Catch each exception and cut-and-paste the behaviour.
2. Catch `Exception` and write the behaviour once.

I personally prefer 1. They're both nasty, but at least with 1 you won't get weird stuff happening when you get `SomeCrazyException` being thrown somewhere down the line.

Comment: what you mean you get __SomeCrazyException__? I don't see the point :-(

Comment: I mean that if there is some other kind of runtime exception that you're not expecting then option 2 will catch it, possibly doing the wrong thing with it. Also, if for some reason the body of the `try...catch` block changes in the future you might get different runtime exceptions that you want to handle differently. Basically, option 2 is a little harder to maintain because it's catching things too broadly.

Comment: @Victor: I just read your answer. I'm talking about the first and second points you mention. **SomeCrazyException** is any `RuntimeException` or any future checked exceptions.

Comment: @Sangdol: I believe I read somewhere that it would allow syntax like `catch (ExceptionClassA | ExceptionClassB b)` or something like that. See http://http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_multi_catch_rethrow

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice article about generic-exceptions [Beware the dangers of generic Exceptions](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2003/jw-1003-generics.html). The author explain several reasons in order to avoid handle generic-exception (with a few exceptions)
. Generally speaking in my opinion these are the relevant points :

- A generic catch (Exception e) catches all subclasses of *RuntimeException*. And according that runtime exceptions indicate programming erros AND is not expected to recover those errors.
- If your code just catches Exception , you'll probably never know if the method you are calling later adds a new checked exception to its method signature.
- The caller may be able to recover from some errors but not from others.
- Logging is limited because only one catch clause doesn't know the specific exception being caught.